# Sitecore 8.1 Rebuild link database getting timeout exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am trying to rebuild the link database but its not getting completed. I am getting timeout exception.
The below the exception I am getting:

```
Job started: RebuildLinkDatabasesIndex|System.Exception: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.Data.DataException: Error executing SQL command:  DELETE FROM [Links] 
                            WHERE [ID] = @id ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Execute>b__14()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Links.SqlLinkDatabase.Compact(Database database)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkDatabase.Rebuild(Database database)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.RebuildLinkDatabase.RebuildLinkDatabaseForm.Builder.Build()|Job ended: RebuildLinkDatabasesIndex (units processed: )
```

Any suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Retryer](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-to-tackle-database-deadlocks#practical-stepssolutions) to replay operation - if that is a random error, retryer shall help
2. [Rebuild SQL Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) so that they perform well
3. Use later platform version where rebuild operation has been optimized